# Array in an odd order

Tags: ruby, algorithm, primes, prime-factoring, factorization

I wrote this to find the prime factorization of a number `num`. It gives the right answers (for example, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2 for `num` 72), but it comes out in an odd order. I can't figure out why. I was wondering if somebody sees something I don't.

```
$primes = [2]
$factors = []
num = 72
max = num

def isprime(n)
 $primes.each do |x|
  if n % x == 0 then
   return
  end
 end
 $primes.push(n)
 return
end

i = 3
while i <= max
 isprime(i)
 i += 1
end

while !($primes.include?(num))
 $primes.each do |x|
  if num % x == 0 then
   $factors.push(x)
   num /= x
  end
 end
end
$factors.push(num)

puts $factors
```

Comment: Why do you expect the numbers to be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the `$primes.each` loop as soon as you find a factor, or it'll complete the loop each time.

```
while !($primes.include?(num))
  $primes.each do |x|
    if num % x == 0 then
      $factors.push(x)
      num /= x
      break
    end
  end
end
$factors.push(num)
```

P.S: I've just kept to the algorithmic side and ignored the Ruby side.

Comment: ok wow, i really thought i had broken after. ha. nice spot, thanks. ps i was coding on my phone. thats my excuse and i'm sticking to it lol

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop works like this. Consider you are testing the number `72`.
Your primes array will be `[2,3,5,7...]`

In the `$primes.each do |x| loop` in the first iteration it will test `num = 72` against `2` and add it to the `factor` array

```
Inner Iteration 1 => factors = [2], x = 2 , num = 36
Inner Iteration 2 => factors = [2,3], x = 3 , num = 12
Inner Iteration 3 => factors = [2,3], x = 5 , num = 12
Inner Iteration 3 => factors = [2,3], x = 7 , num = 12
Inner Iteration 3 => factors = [2,3], x = 11, num = 12
```

Now the inner iteration exists and the prime loop begins again from `2`.

```
Inner Iteration 1 => factors = [2,3,2], x = 2 , num = 6
Inner Iteration 2 => factors = [2,3,2,3], x = 3 , num = 2
```

Inner loop starts again

```
Inner Iteration 1 => factors = [2,3,2,3,2], x = 2 , num = 2
```

You have to put a break inside the inner loop to just do the first factorization and exit.

```
while !($primes.include?(num))
 $primes.each do |x|
  if num % x == 0 then
   $factors.push(x)
   num /= x
   break
  end
end
```